# Windows 10 connected to two different networks, both having same subnet mask

Tags: windows-10, networking

I'm using Windows 10 Home on PC with two network interfaces:

- Cable (ethernet) connected to router from ISP,
- Wi-Fi connected to camera that creates its own network and exposes its video stream through `192.168.1.1:somePort`.

Issue is that both router from ISP and the camera have same subnet (`192.168.1.0/24`). I have no control over these settings. Effectively, I cannot access `192.168.1.1` on camera, because system defaults to router's gateway (and that's good actually, I'd rather want camera on different subnet).

I'm familiar with basics of networks, but I'm not sure if NAT is a correct approach to translate whole subnet, say from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.2.1` and so on. I definitely couldn't find any settings or operations that allow that. I think I'm taking a wrong approach or missing something.

If something described above would be impossible, I just need to access ISP router's network just like it was the only network available, while only accessing stream from camera's network. I don't need to access whole camera's network as a separate subnet.

[image: Reference diagram]

Comment: This can never work. Networks are required to have a different subnet + mask. You have to reconfigure either the router or the camera to use a different subnet. Check the manual of camera and router for a web gui and how to change the network addresses.

Comment: If you provide the make/model of your router and camera, maybe someone could provide instructions for reconfiguring them.

Comment: I reformatted your question a bit, you might want to replace the X I used for the subnet value with the actual value (for `255.255.255.0` it will be `24`).

Comment: Can you explain `Wi-Fi connected to camera that creates its own network and exposes its video stream through 192.168.1.1:somePort`? What do you mean by two networks? As far as I understand the "networks" are connected via wired/wireless Ethernet, which makes them one network (LAN)?!

Comment: I hope that [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeOlpAQ7tAM) will make it clear for you. I suppose that you declined possibility of such uncommon, overkill and unsafe design to expose camera's video wirelessly, but that's the hardware I have at hand right now.

Comment: On a side topic, I even found more about the camera in those two sources: [1](http://hackeken.blogspot.com/2017/01/reverse-engineering-eken-android-app.html#more), [2](https://pcburn.com/eken-h9-h9r-h9s-wifi-connection-from-vlc/)... :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but if you can not change your routers IP (`192.168.1.1/x`) and your cam's IP (`192.168.1.1/x`) - which is very uncommon, you need to put then on separate LANs (physically or via VLAN). On the same LAN you will always get an IP conflict.

Put a router with NAT on your cam's network and you should be able to access it. I didn't understand how you want to connect everything if you could provide a diagram so we can give you more detailed information.

FYI (again if I understand correctly), the problem is not that you are using "two networks" with the same subnet mask (that is by definition the same logical network), and connecting those networks via WLAN or Ethernetcable essentially makes it one LAN. The problem is, that you assigned the same IP address twice on the same LAN.

Comment: That's correct, changing router's gateway to 192.168.1.2 made camera's stream available. But this is not a solution I asked for. I want to avoid any impact on my home LAN configuration from random devices like that camera I tried to connect. That's why I assumed in my question that router is not configurable. I wonder if I can configure mapping described in original question on operating system level.

Comment: @CodeSculptor the "routing" in your OS is IP based (Layer 3) so you can not forward to different interfaces based on port. One solution I can think of is installing a virtual router so it can forward to the appropriate HW-NIC based on port. But there are better ways to avoid impact. You might still be focusing on the wrong problems/solutions. Might be a good idea to write a "straight up" question, those "assumptions" usually don't work very well.

Comment: You have reassured me now that "straight up" questions lead to answers that I don't look for. I asked for a solution, not a workaround. As a workaround, I have connected my old unused phone to camera. Works? Works. It is even better than changing router's subnet to avoid the collission (it doesn't affect router and connections of all devices around it). It still doesn't answer my original question about solution done using Windows 10. Going back to topic, should I end this discussion on conclusion that it is impossible (on OS level) to map IP (from a specific interface) to another IP?

Comment: If by "OS level" you mean "just some configuration in Win10" without additional software, then no.

Comment: @CodeSculptor you could try [Portforwarding](http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/) (it's suppose to work with Win10 but I never tried it)

Comment: Thank you Albin. I saw that before asking here. I think it doesn't have parameter that would point to specific interface (in essence, without knowing about interface, it uses 192.168.1.1 that is already resolved from conflict - and in my case it was router's gateway). On more positive side, I started looking into other netsh commands again and I realized I was researching it in wrong way. I have to get better understanding of `netsh interface ipv4 add route`, because either I understand it in wrong way, or I use it in wrong way.

Comment: @CodeSculptor yes, I think that is the problem. "add route" is to setup routes to routers, not to exchange the destination IP of the paket. Try to watch a few vids about router setup in a local network, this will give you a better overall understanding in this scenario.

Comment: @CodeSculptor PS. I would appreciate a +1 or an accept - this answer might not be the final solution (although I fear there is no solution without additional tools) it has been quite time-intensive

Comment: @CodeSculptor yes, I think that is the problem. "add route" is to setup routes to routers (gateways), not to change the destination IP of the a paket (that's what NAT does). Try to watch a few vids about router setup in a local network, this will give you a better overall understanding in this scenario.

Comment: Maybe some background information about NAT (and PAT) will be helpful as well (this is what you actually wanted to do). From there you probably will end up with NAT on routers, proxies etc. anyway ...

Comment: @CodeSculptor I just came by a software called (portmapper)[http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/pmapper/Freeware.htm], it might be worth checking it out...